# "Getting a 'build error, message: no EcucValueCollection element on path' in my project. How can I resolve this issue?"

Tags: automation, embedded, autosar, automotive

"I'm currently working on a BSW (Basic Software) module for code generation, and I've encountered a specific error during my work. I'm receiving the following error message: 'build error, message: no EcucValueCollection element on path.' Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a BSW module you need an EcucValueCollection with specific configuration containers in it. Those containers and the parameters within describe the module's settings; they must be configured specifically for the hardware and application combination.

I'm not sure which toolchain you are using but the message says that the build process can not find those values. You should look for the ARXML files containing the module's configuration and add them to the process path.

Comment: Thanks alot for reply, yes thats what I did and I have found the values which i am using was incorrect, but its solved now.